# Not able to take pull, push, merge from bitbucket using Narzo 20 mobile data 4G

Tags: git, bitbucket, ubuntu-18.04, git-push, linux-mint-19

I'm trying to pull code from Bitbucket using mobile network. I'm using Narzo 20. Android version is 11.

My mobile network is 4G and it's not slow. And no issues with mobile internet browsing etc. I tried using both USB tethering and mobile hotspot but no solution.

But the real confusion is that when i try with my friend's mobile phone, it works. I don't know what's going on and not able to get answer from online. I'm using Linux  Mint Tricia 19.3

I don't know a whack about git and how to solve this.
Please help me folks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VPN service to connect to internet on top of Mobile Data.
I face this problem as well. The problem goes away if I use US based VPN.

Comment: still not working.

Comment: Then unfortunately I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, and I think it was because the phone was using ipv6 addresses.

I added:

104.192.141.1 bitbucket.org

to my /etc/hosts file and that cured it for me.

ref: [bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/connecting-to-bitbucket-org-over-ipv6-840796883.html)

Comment: after phone software upgrade, it's working fine now.